# Select from tables in SQL Server with equals conditions

Tags: sql-server-2012

Please see my data snapshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA8Mq.png)

I want to achieve the following:

```
select record 
where (`adslocationdescription` = "jawa timur" and `type` = 1) or     
      (`adslocationdescription` != 'jawa timur and `type` = 2)
```

but if `adscampaigncode` has a record that equals (`adslocationdesc` = "jawa timur" and `type`=2), no data should be selected.

Comment: what have you tried so far? where are you struggling?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of (code not tested):

```
select * from myTable
where (AdsLocationDescription = 'Jawa Timur' AND (Type = 1 OR Type = 2))
AND AdsCampaignCode NOT IN
-- this subquery gets AdsCampaignCodes that 
-- DO have LocationDescription of Jawa Timur
(select distinct AdsCampaignCode
from myTable
where AdsLocationDescription = 'Jawa Timur')
```